Sharing variables between two seperatly running Python scripts
I am trying to get a Python 3.11 script with a flask app talking to a fully separate Python 2.7 script that is controlling a robot. The Python 3.11 file creates angles that the robot arm receives.
The current problem is that I haven't found a way to get a list of angles from one program to the next. Also, the sending of the angles has to be very fast because they are being created from a live video. The function to send the angles currently looks like this:
def sendAngles(videomodus,liste): # videomodus is a variable to make clear if its a list of lists with angles or just a list with angles
   # this function gets called every frame

I have already tried using socket and writing to a file, but in both situation, both programs get stuck.

Can you please share a minimum worked example of your socket and/or file code?

In general, the way to share data between different scripts is by putting it in a file.

my first idea what to use file - one script append at the end of file, other script reads (without closing to read only new data). But if you use flask then other program could use urllib or requests to get new data from flask (as plain text or JSON). Other script would need to run loop to send requests all time.

I now use pipe for sending the list between the two programs.
Sender:
import json 
import os

check_path = '/home/alex/robbi-master/robbi/pipes/check'
listen_path = '/home/alex/robbi-master/robbi/pipes/liste'

if not os.path.exists(check_path):
    os.mkfifo(check_path)
if not os.path.exists(listen_path):
    os.mkfifo(listen_path)

def sendwinkel(videoModus, liste):
    if not videoModus:
        with open(listen_path, 'w') as liste_fifo:
            data = json.dumps(liste)
            liste_fifo.write(data)
        with open(check_path, 'r') as check:
            check.read()
    elif videoModus:
        a = 0
        while a < liste.length:
            with open(listen_path, 'w') as liste_fifo:
                data = json.dumps(liste[a])
                liste_fifo.write(data)
            with open(check_path, 'r') as check:
                check.read()
            a += 1


Receiver (ros script):
def go_to_joint_state(self):
        
    joint_goal  = self.group.get_current_joint_values()

    with open(listen_path, 'r') as listen_fifo:
        data = listen_fifo.read()
        joint_goal = json.loads(data)
        #self.group.go(joint_goal, wait=True)
        print(joint_goal)
    with open(check_path, 'w') as check:
        check.write('ok')
    self.group.stop() 

